# How did fogbugz implement its screenshot feature?

Tags: fogbugz, webpage-screenshot

Does anyone know how FogBugz implemented the "taking a screenshot of the current work screen" feature? Is this done purely via php? Perl? A flash script?

Answer (score 3):

FogBugz includes a small application for Mac or Windows which takes a screen grab and then HTTP POSTs it to a page in FogBugz which puts the image in the database and attaches it to a case. It is pretty bare-bones; for something beefier, check out [TechSmith SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) which has [FogBugz integration](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/accessories/fogbugz.asp) like the built-in tool.

The Windows version of the FogBugz screenshot utility is written in C++ with MFC -- it's a Windows app that works by getting a compatible DC and bitblt-ing the screen into it, then converting to PNG. The Mac version was written using Real Basic and relies on the built in Grab functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure this isn't how FogBugz does it, but it can be done entirely server-side in perl using [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)'s content_as_png method (running Firefox on a server and talking to it via the Mozrepl plugin).

Update: I see there are a number of questions with the webpage-screenshot tag; you might take a look through them and see if there's an answer that works for you there.